# Case Statement Issue using 2 Metrics in Data Studio

Tags: looker-studio

I've got a case statement that uses 2 numbers, however, I get the error;

"an expression can have either metrics, or dimensions, but not both".

Not sure what's going on here.

My case statement is as follows;

```
Case When Num1 > 0 then Price else 0 End
```

Num 1 is an int value.
Price is a calculated value which is Spent/Num1

My reason for doing this is to avoid the "No Data" box and to just show a 0.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look on [this](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7359285?hl=en):

> While useful, CASE has a significant limitation: it can't mix dimensions and metrics in the same statement. If you try, you'll get an error in Data Studio  saying, "An expression can have either metrics, or dimensions, but not both."

I suspect that you might have *Num1* as [Dimension](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6402048?hl=en&ref_topic=7441655) and *Price* as [Metric](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6402048?hl=en&ref_topic=7441655), or vice versa.

I have created a simple table, and your case statement worked for me. Here I have *Num1*, *Price* and *Spent* as Dimension. 
[image]

Comment: They're both "blue" which means metric. I also ensured they are numbers and not currency just in case.

Is there something going on in "Price" when I'm doing a division in that field? Does a formula convert it to a dimension?

Comment: @Pavlo, Can you show a complete image including all the fields?

Comment: Found the issue. Field names were the problem. Renamed them to have proper names. Having that "- Adviews" was interfering. I remove the dashes.